# Can we have meaningful operator names dynamically generated in flink-sql based streaming applications

Tags: flink-streaming, flink-sql

Kaka topic (input: table1,table2, output: table3)

Flink SQL Streaming job

```
CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW distinct_table1 AS
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY change_date desc) AS rownum
FROM table1)
WHERE rownum = 1;


CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW distinct_table2 AS
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY change_date desc) AS rownum
FROM table2)
WHERE rownum = 1;


Insert into table3
Select t1.col1,t1.col2..,t1.coln,t2.col1,t2.col2,t2.coln
From distinct_table t1 inner join distinct_table t2 on t1.id=t2.t1_id
```

- source operators names are generated like **Source: table1[7] -> MiniBatchAssigner[8] -> Calc[9]**
- Distinct SQL clause creates an operator like **Rank[20] -> Calc[21]**
- Join clause creates an operator something like **Join[23] -> Calc[24]**

Question#1: For effective monitoring, is this possible if we can have table name included in the operator name?
Question#2: What does number in brackets represents [7], [20],[21] ? Does it has any association with TaskSlot assignment?